# display document of certain content type by user group

Tags: permissions, content-type, view

I've a document library with some content type.
I'd like to show the document to user group depending on content type.

For example:

i have the following content types ct1, ct2, ct3 and the following user groups ug1, ug2, ug3

ug1 should show ct1 and ct2

ug2 show ct2

ug3 show ct3

Do you know how i could go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solutionned the issue with a workflow and an action replace list item permission

I test on wich content type i'm and i set the related permission